# Remove validators from relay chain

Tags: polkadot-js, validator, relay-chain

what are the commands to remove both **validators** (Alice and bob) from Relay-chain in Linux OS ?

Comment: if Alice and Bob are validators then are they being run on a standalone chain and connected to a relay chain via a bridge? Or are Alice and Bob collators?

Comment: I want to Purge the validators

Comment: Have you tried to use PolkadoJS: `Developer -> Sudo -> validatorManager.deregisterValidators()` ?

Comment: If i run, this error comes:  Prepared block for proposing at 778 (8 ms) [hash: 0xa83337f768d6b1811130a0f6ff1d43bc5425e65c7ede352362606c7f5618636a; parent_hash: 0xd3cb…e7be; extrinsics (2): [0x3866…add7, 0xcb0d…1786]]
2022-06-07 18:31:00  Pre-sealed block for proposal at 778. Hash now 0x25bfe9c9be345bfcec6ca3a3c56b65a254cf8f71c210907427e0b134853fabc0, previously 0xa83337f768d6b1811130a0f6ff1d43bc5425e65c7ede352362606c7f5618636a.
2022-06-07 18:31:00 Error with block built on 0xd3cbe75706aa06b2ee91b1aa7c1316e458f72af9b7f282bab2d91278e2b5e7be: Import failed: Unexpected epoch change

Comment: @DeepakChaudhary that sounds like an issue with the consensus mechanism. What are your chain specifications?

Comment: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/707/after-restarting-a-chain-i-get-a-clientimportunexpect-epoch-change-error-wh is the issue, you want to reset your nodes database with the `--purge` command. See `--help` for use there.

Comment: Checkout https://substrate.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask to get familiar with best practices to get support of the community here :)