# Finalization issue based on unexpected epoch change

Tags: finality, rococo-local

On my rococo local relay chain, I found the unexpected epoch change when the finalized block stuck but the best block continue to generate. And when the issue happened, only one node show me this issue. Is that possible I can fix the finalized issue?

My env is only two polkadot valdiators on 0.9.39 version.

Updated: There are more error message

```
2024-01-16 08:59:11 Chain between (0x1fef…7459, 3182191) and 3180950 not fully known. Forcing vote on 3180950 unknown_number=3182191 unknown_hash=0x1fef1299626dc072943ed903233383e275abb1f09a5fac44c490931470ee7459
2024-01-16 08:59:11 Call to `DetermineUndisputedChain` failed error=DetermineUndisputedChainCanceled(Canceled)
2024-01-16 08:59:11 error=RollingSessionWindow(SessionsUnavailable { kind: Missing(318098), info: Some(SessionsUnavailableInfo { window_start: 318096, window_end: 319290, block_hash: 0x1fef1299626dc072943ed903233383e275abb1f09a5fac44c490931470ee7459 }) })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After restarting a chain I get a ClientImport("Unexpect epoch change") error. What does this mean in English?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/707/after-restarting-a-chain-i-get-a-clientimportunexpect-epoch-change-error-wh)

Comment: Partially, because when I used the time warp method (copied all of the data, revert the unfinalized block, setup time on my local system), it showed the error

```
2024-01-15 12:08:00 Skipping chain: unable to gather info about imported block (0x4aee7d7263413bc5502369e47e58b9cf84ace05ed12635150f7a6001cd245f25, 3180951): block is from an ancient session
```