# How to fetch all accounts in a pallet?

Tags: substrate-node-template, account, balances

I need to change the balances of all the **accounts** in my custom pallet, For that first i need to fetch the accounts in the pallet. How to do this?

Comment: Of a pallet different than FRAME System? Or for FRAME System? (the default for Substrate blockchains)

Comment: Might be duplicate of: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/180/how-can-we-get-a-snapshot-of-all-balances-at-a-certain-block

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I'm building new custom pallet, their I need to fetch all the accounts present in our chain_state and then increase some balance.How to perform this?

Comment: What do you mean "change"? Through transfer or migration?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier I need to add 10 unit balance to all the accounts after every 5 blocks. Can we Do it?

Comment: Alright. My question is do you want to do this by sending transactions or making this a logic of this pallet?

Comment: @AurevoirXavier I need to make a logic in a custom pallet in which after every 5 block all account's(alice,bob etc.) balances should increase by 10 unit. Is this clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [storage iter keys](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageMap.html#method.iter_keys), and put this logic in `on_initialize`.

Pseudo code:

```rs
fn on_initialize(n: BlockNumber) {
  // Run this every 5 blocks.
  if n % 5 != 0 { return; }

  <Accounts<T>>::iter_keys().for_each(|a| {
    transfer(a, 10 * UNIT);
  });
}
```

Note, if the `Accounts` map is large, this would require a lot of weight. Be careful with this.

---

I don't agree with @bkchr's comment.

As I said this would cost a lot of weight, you need to pay more attention to this.

But it's still reasonable to have this in the pallet.

If your pallet is about building up a small group. And there are always a few people in the group(`your_pallet::Accounts<T>`), it's okay to use this.

In the past, this is exactly how staking reward distribution got implemented in Substrate. But as the number of Kusama validators/nominators grows up, they have to find another way to do this.

So, I won't say this is wrong at all. Just take some measures before you use this. Check if this fits your case.

Comment: How to convert BlockNumber into i32?

Comment: e.g. `let n = n.saturated_into::<u32>()`, https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_arithmetic/traits/trait.SaturatedConversion.html#method.saturated_into

Comment: what dependency need to add for this?

Comment: I have already sent the crate's link in the previous comment.

Comment: Never ever do this! This will so easily break your runtime. This is just wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of increasing the balance of every account every 5 blocks is a bad idea. Your chain would be very easily attack-able by creating a lot of accounts and thus forcing you to iterate over all these accounts. There are multiple ways to achieve what you are trying to do, without killing your chain.

1. If you only have a subset of accounts. You could have a map of `LastUpdated<AccountId, Block>`. Then users would need to call a `mint` function and that calculates the amount of coins they are getting since the last time they called `mint` and then you need to update `LastUpdated`. This is a "lazy" way where the user need to do interact with the chain to get its funds.
2. If you really want to increase the balance of every account. You could make every account balance be a percentage of the total supply. Then each time you want to increase the balance of all the accounts, you simply increase the total supply. But be aware that while this would work, nothing in FRAME is written in such a way currently.